# How to display part of a screen on another?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to display only the part of a screen on another, quite like having a screen part-splitter, or a zoom-on-another-screen function.

I am currently splitting my display between two monitors, with a VGA-splitter, but I would indeed rather have only a part of my "first" monitor displayed on the second.

If I used a virtual desktop with some apps clipped on my first monitor AND the virtual desktop, could it work? Would I have to get a second graphic card to dual-monitor my computer and display the virtual desktop on the second screen? Moreover, what annoys me with this solution is that I do not want everything I do on my first screen to be displayed on the second and I do not want to used three monitors in order to get this functionality...

Any ideas to help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ATI Series graphic card and this card must be higher then 2600 HD series you can use Hydra Grid and Multiple Desktop Functions thats you need it but if you don't have ATI Series Graphic card you can use 3rd party programs like a "Dexpot" thats handy and free